# Issues with parsing Docker hostname into IP address using VUE and VITE

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, vuejs3, vite

I am currently using `Vue3`, `Vite` and `Docker`. Inside a `docker-compose.yml` file, I am trying to pass one of my services address as a URL into another service, but it seems to be read as a string value. I have ensured they are on the same network as well.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  backend:
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.backend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  frontend:
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.frontend
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    environment:
      - VITE_VUE_APP_PREDICT_URL= backend 
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
```

Following a post on Medium talking about how Vue and Vite statically inserts the environment variables, I tried the method where a placeholder value is initially set for the env variable and a `shell` script is ran after to replace the files in the `dist` folder with the address but the error I seem to get is:

```
team08-frontend-1      | sed: can't read ./dist/js/*.js*: No such file or directory
team08-frontend-1      | sed: can't read ./dist/precache-manifest*.js: No such file or directory
```

My shell script consists of the following
**replace_env.sh**

```
ROOT_DIR=./dist
# Replace env vars in files served by NGINX
for file in $ROOT_DIR/js/*.js* $ROOT_DIR/index.html $ROOT_DIR/precache-manifest*.js;
do
's|VITE_VUE_APP_PREDICT_URL_PLACEHOLDER|'${VITE_VUE_APP_PREDICT_URL}'|g' $file
  # Your other variables here...
done

npm run dev -- --host 0.0.0.0
```

and it is called in my **Dockerfile.frontend** with the following line:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "./update_env.sh" ]
```

I currently have a placeholder `.env` file in the root folder as well, with the lines

**.env**

```
VITE_VUE_APP_PREDICT_URL=VITE_VUE_APP_PREDICT_URL_PLACEHOLDER
```

After running `npm run dev`, I used `Docker` commands and `cat .env` to open the `.env` file and it prints out the **NOT REPLACED** placeholder value.

```
VITE_VUE_APP_PREDICT_URL=VITE_VUE_APP_PREDICT_URL_PLACEHOLDER
```

However, in my frontend when I do a `console.log(process.env)`, the value I get is `backend` which is the **string value** that is passed in by my `docker-compose.yml` file. I have added the following to my `vite.config.js` too.

**vite.config.js**

```
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd());
  return {
    plugins: [vue()],
    define: {
      'process.env': env,
    },
  };
});
```

Do advise.

Comment: Your Vue application is probably running in the end user's browser.  That's not inside a container (and isn't necessarily on the same machine) and it can't use any Docker networking features.  You need to connect to the backend's `ports:` using the host's DNS name or IP address.